# Python wheel version

Tags: python, linux, scipy, ubuntu-16.04, python-wheel

I want to use python wheel for SciPy. I found this site for download: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy.

There are two options for python 2.7 and x86_64: cp27m and cp27mu. What is the difference between them? One is working, the other not and I want to know why.

Answer (score 2):

These are two different Linux distributions that are configurations of CPython. m is the version for narrow-unicode and mu is the version for wide-unicode. You can follow this link for more information: https://github.com/pypa/manylinux . Hope this helps!